# Do I need to book some intra-Europe tickets to apply for Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe

I already booked my ultra-Europe ticket which was a roundtrip from YVR to ZRH.

However, I am not sure whether I need to book for intra-Europe tickets for my visa application.

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/does-schengen-visa-proof-of-transport-requirement-include-travel-inside-europe

Comment: Why would you need to book intra-Europe tickets?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, you don't *need* to buy anything (not even the ticket out of the Schengen area) but you need to credibly establish the purpose of your trip. And sometimes a reservation could help with that.

See [Does Schengen visa proof of transport requirement include travel inside Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/does-schengen-visa-proof-of-transport-requirement-include-travel-inside-europe) for a discussion of the underlying logic in a somewhat different context.